# Projection operator $P$ on the plane orthogonal to a given vector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, projection-matrices

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, we are asked to determine the matrix $P$, and its eigenvalues, corresponding to the projector of a vector on the plane orthogonal to
$$\underline{v}=\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 2 \\ -3 \end{matrix}\right]$$

---

I think that the request is to determine the projector on the plane $W$ such that:
$$W \oplus V = \mathbb{R^3}$$
where $V=\operatorname{span}(\underline{v})$ and $W=V^\perp$. A basis for $W$ could be:
$$\{\underline{w}_1, \underline{w}_2\} = \{ \left[\begin{matrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right] \} $$
To extract a orthonormalized basis of $W$ I can apply Gram Schmidt algorithm.
So a vector projected on $W$:
$$x_w= (u_1, x)u_1+(u_2, x)u_2$$ 
Where $\{u_1, u_2\}$ are orthonormalized vectors basis of $W$. How can I find the matrix of the projection?

---

After some pther researches I found that
$$P= u_1 u_1^T + u_2u_2^T$$
So I ask: **if this proceeding is correct, is there an easier way to get this result?**

Comment: You missed a method. Given *any* basis of of a subspace $W$, the orthogonal projection matrix is $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, where $A$ is the matrix that has the basis vectors as its columns. In this case G-S is less work, though, and computing the projection onto $v$ and subtracting it from the identity (per fredgoodman’s answer) is even less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given two methods, both correct.  For the first method, you have correctly expressed your projection $P$ as a linear operator.  To find the matrix with respect to the standard basis, use the rule that the $j$-th column is $P(e_j)$  where $e_j$ is the $j$-th standard basis element.  You can check, both conceptually and computationally that this agrees with your second formula.

Yet another method, which avoids the computation of $u_1, u_2$ entirely, so is probably better:  the projector onto the plane perpendicular to $v$ is the identity minus the projector onto the span of $v$,
$$
P(x) = x - \frac{\langle x, v \rangle }{||v||^2} v.
$$
Again to find the matrix, the same rule applies.  The the $j$-th column is $P(e_j)$.  Again, you can check by computation that this will agree with your other methods.

Comment: thank you. So $P_V=\frac{v v^T}{||v||^2}$ and $P_W=\mathbb{I}-P_V$?

Comment: Does this relation come from the projection theorem?

Comment: as for the eigenvalues, I know that a projector has only 0 and 1 as eigenvalues. So I think that $P(v)=0 v$ since $v $ is orthogonal to our plane and $P(w_1)=1 w_1 $, $P(w_2)=1 w_2$ where $w_1, w_2$ are the eigenvectors of the projection (so they should be part of $W$ )

Comment: Everything you say is correct.   I'm not sure what you refer to as the "projection theorem".

Comment: According to my book the projection theorem states that given a Hilbert space H, a subspace M in H, a vector $x \in H$ can be written in one and one only way as $x=p+w$ with $ p \in M, w \in M^\perp$

Comment: OK, and that is the same as saying proj onto M plus proj onto M perp is the identity.  Also note that the two projections are orthogonal in the sense that their product in either order is zero.

Comment: I think you understand everything here, but it is also a good idea to actually compute your projections by the three methods.