# Project vector on orthogonal vector plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

With two 3-dimensional vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$:

> How can I get the projected vector of $\vec{w}$ on the orthogonal plane of vector $\vec{v}$?

[image]

Comment: This answers your question: [Projection operator $P$ on the plane orthogonal to a given vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654353/projection-operator-p-on-the-plane-orthogonal-to-a-given-vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substract the projection of $\vec{w}$ on $\vec{v}$ from itself in order to get rid of the part of $\vec{w}$ that is parallel to $\vec{v}$, hence the solution $\displaystyle \vec{w} - \frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}}{\|\vec{v}\|^2} \,\vec{v}\;$ (N.B. : the second term corresponds to the dotted line between $\vec{w}$ and the plane).

Comment: It is a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval It needed 3 min to answer, not a great deal, but I can delete my answer if you wish.

Comment: the suggested duplicate is too much math jargon for me... I am really happy with this simple (and fast) answer

Comment: @BillDubuque I honestly don't know what to think about this.